# Problema de leitura em arquivo.txt

Tags: java

Boa tarde!
Estou com problemas para resolver a leitura do meu código quando é utilizada a entrada via arquivo .txt, já realizei correções, troquei métodos, tudo, mas não funciona, continua apresentando o mesmo erro, é para trabalho da faculdade e já não tenho mais a quem recorrer.
o problema: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at ACMESports.criarAtletaXMedalha(ACMESports.java:81)
at ACMESports.executar(ACMESports.java:27)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ACMESports {
private Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);  // Atributo para entrada de dados
private PrintStream saidaPadrao = System.out;   // Guarda a saida padrao - tela (console)
private final String nomeArquivoEntrada = "dadosin.txt";  // Nome do arquivo de entrada de dados
private final String nomeArquivoSaida = "dadosout.txt";  // Nome do arquivo de saida de dados
private Medalheiro medalheiro;
private Plantel plantel;

```
public ACMESports() {
    plantel = new Plantel();
    medalheiro = new Medalheiro();
    redirecionaES();
}

public void executar() {
    registrarAtleta();
    //registrarMedalhas();
    criarAtletaXMedalha();
    //informacoesAtletas();
    //informacoesAtletas();
    //informacoesMedalhas();
    //mostrarPaisDosAtletas();
    //mostraAtletasMedalhasInfo();
    //mostraAtletasMedalhasInfo();
    //mostrarAtlteasDeModalidade();
    //mostrarAtletacomMaisMedalhas();
}

private void registrarAtleta() {
    String nome = "";
    int numero = 0;
    String pais = "";
    while(numero!=-1) {
        numero = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine();
        nome = entrada.nextLine();
        pais = entrada.nextLine();
        Atleta a = new Atleta(numero, nome, pais);
        Plantel.cadastraAtleta(a);
        System.out.println(a.toStringAtleta());
    }
}

private void registrarMedalhas() {
    int codigo;
    int tipo;
    boolean individual;
    String modalidade;
    codigo = entrada.nextInt();
    entrada.nextLine();
    while(codigo != -1) {
        tipo = entrada.nextInt();
        individual = entrada.nextBoolean();
        entrada.nextLine();
        modalidade = entrada.nextLine();
        Medalha m = new Medalha(codigo, tipo, individual, modalidade);
        boolean codigoduplicado = false; // cria um atributo originalmente falso, como condição de "vazio"
        if(Medalheiro.consultaMedalha(codigo) != null) {
            codigoduplicado = true; // caso seja true, indica que já há cadastro daquele atleta.
        }else {
            Medalheiro.cadastraMedalha(m);
            System.out.println(m.toStringMedalha());
        }
        codigo = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine();
    }
}

private void criarAtletaXMedalha() {
    int codigo = 0;
    int numero = 0;
    codigo = entrada.nextInt();
    numero = entrada.nextInt();
    while(codigo != -1 || numero !=-1) {
        Medalha m = Medalheiro.consultaMedalha(codigo);
        Atleta a = Plantel.consultaAtleta(numero);
        if (m != null && a != null){
            Medalha.adicionaAtleta(a);
            Atleta.adicionaMedalha(m);
            System.out.println(a+", "+m);
        }else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }
}

private void informacoesAtletas(int numero){
    numero = entrada.nextInt();
    if(Plantel.consultaAtleta(numero) != null){
        String a = Atleta.toStringAtleta();
        System.out.println(a);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Nenhum atleta encontrado.");
    }
}

private void informacoesAtletas(String nome){
    nome = entrada.nextLine();
    if(Plantel.consultaAtleta(nome) != null){
        String a = Atleta.toStringAtleta();
        System.out.println(a);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Nenhum atleta encontrado.");
    }
}

private void informacoesMedalhas(int codigo){
    codigo = entrada.nextInt();
    if(Medalheiro.consultaMedalha(codigo) != null){
    String m = Medalha.toStringMedalha();
        System.out.println(m);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Nenhuma medalha encontrada.");
    }
}

private void mostrarPaisDosAtletas(String pais){
    pais = entrada.nextLine();
    if(Plantel.consultaPais(pais) != null){
        String a = Atleta.toStringAtleta();
        System.out.println(a);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Nenhum atleta encontrado neste país.");
    }
}

private void mostraAtletasMedalhasInfo(int tipo){
    tipo = entrada.nextInt();
    if(Medalheiro.consultaMedalhaPorTipo(tipo)){
        String a = Atleta.toStringAtleta();
        System.out.println(a);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Nenhum atleta encontrado neste país.");
    }
}

private void mostrarAtlteasDeModalidade(){
    ArrayList<Medalha> modalidade = Medalheiro.buscaModalidade();
    for (Medalha medalha : modalidade){
        ArrayList<Atleta> atletas = medalha.getAtleta();
        for (Atleta atleta : atletas){
            if (atletas != null){
                System.out.println("Modalidade: "+modalidade+"");
            }
        }
    }
}

private void mostrarAtletacomMaisMedalhas(){
    Plantel.ContarAtletaComMaisMedalhas();
}

private void redirecionaES() {
    try {
        BufferedReader streamEntrada = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nomeArquivoEntrada));
        entrada = new Scanner(streamEntrada);   // Usa como entrada um arquivo
        PrintStream streamSaida = new PrintStream(new File(nomeArquivoSaida), String.valueOf(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        System.setOut(streamSaida);             // Usa como saida um arquivo
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);   // Ajusta para ponto decimal
    entrada.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);   // Ajusta para leitura para ponto decimal
}

private void restauraES() {
    System.setOut(saidaPadrao);
    entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

}

O problema sempre da ao tentar realizar a leitura do registrarMedalhas, após isso o programa para.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.